# How can I go reverse in a switch case

Tags: c++, arduino

I have 2 LEDs and when I press a button it should change the pattern in this order: off, first LED on, both LEDs on, second LED on.
Now I want to add a second button that does the same but in reverse: second LED on, both LEDs on, first LED on, Off.

I tried creating a second switch-case, but it doesn't work.

Code:

```
void loop()
{
  increase.update();
  decrease.update();

  //~~~Increase LED Pattern~~~
  if (increase.fell())
  {
    isPressed = true;
    changePattern();
  }
  else if (digitalRead(Button_Mode) == HIGH)
  {
    isPressed = false;
  }


  //~~~Decrease LED Pattern~~~
  if (decrease.fell())
  {
    isPressed = true;
    decreasePattern();
  }
  else if (digitalRead(Button_Mode) == HIGH)
  {
    isPressed = false;
  }
}


//-----------------Methods------------------
//~~~selects a pattern~~~
void increasePattern()
{
  switch (lightPattern)
  {
    case OFF:
      lightPattern = LED_1;
      digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
      break;

    case LED_1:
      lightPattern = LED_12;
      digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
      break;

    case LED_12:
      lightPattern = LED_2;
      digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
      break;

    case LED_2:
      lightPattern = OFF;
      digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
      break;
  }
}


void decreasePattern()
{
  switch (lightPattern)
  {
    case LED_2:
      lightPattern = LED_12;
      digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
      break;

    case LED_12:
      lightPattern = LED_1;
      digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
      break;

    case LED_1:
      lightPattern = OFF;
      digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
      break;

    case OFF:
      lightPattern = LED_2;
      digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
      break;
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just start with the opposite LED state for the 2nd one??

Comment: "It doesn't work" is utterly useless to focus helpers to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your other answers are fine, but I wanted to sketch out a slightly different approach. Use the buttons to increment or decrement a "state" value (take care of wrap-around!). Use a separate routine to turn on or off the LEDs depending on this state. The code inside `loop()` becomes simple. The hard part is writing the "isButton1Pressed()" routine!  The point of all this is to separate the "input" from the "processing" from the "output". Each routine has a small, clearly defined, part to play. Hope this helps! Have fun!

```
const byte numstates = 4;

byte currentState = 0;      // counter with values 0..(numstate-1) only

void nextState() {
  currentState++;
  if (currentState >= numstates) {
    currentState = 0;
  }
}

void previousState() {
  currentState--;
  if (currentState < 0) {
    currentState = numstates-1;
  }
}

void showPattern() {
   switch (currentState) {
    case 0: // turn off LEDs
        // code here...
        break;
    case 1: // turn on LED1; turn off LED2
        // code here...
        break;
    // repeat for states 2 and 3
   }
}

void loop() {
    if (button1pressed()) {
        nextState();
    } else if (button2pressed()) {
        previousState();
    }
    showPattern();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int stateLed1 = HIGH;

digitalWrite(LED_1, stateLed1);
digitalWrite(LED_2, !stateLed1);
```

Comment: While the code may solve the OP's problem, it's always nice to add a brief explanation of how and why the shown code does so.

Answer (score 0):

I think try `if`. Here is an short example:

```
if (digitalRead(btn)==1){
 val++;
 if (val==2){//write here max versions of led status
  val=0;}
 pulseIn(btn,HIGH);
}
switch(val){
case 0: digitalWrite(led,0); break;
case 1: digitalWrite(led,1); break;
//write here other options
}
```

I think this is easy, but your code is too complicate.

Good luck!